# Add custom product attribute for cart

Tags: magento

I need to create a new attribute on cart products, similar to quantity. I expect the user to enter a value in a textbook for every cart item. How do I add this attribute? Will this be a custom attribute on product with visible false?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps for do this work.

1. Create product attribute (type = TextBox)
2. Add text box in cart page
3. Using observer get text box value and add in attribute.